# adding items in spinner at runtime

Tags: java, android, runtime, android-spinner

How to add values in a spinner at runtime?

I am using a spinner in which i want to add items from a list of another class. I am using the following code but it is giving me null pointer exception.

```
ArrayAdapter<Address> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Address>(
    this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    HomePage.NearPlaces
);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
);
Place.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The LogCat output:

```
INFO/ActivityManager(96): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.emx.OnDaMove/.SpotMe } from pid 20881
WARN/ActivityManager(96): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40705eb0 com.emx.OnDaMove/.HomePage}
DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(20881): Shutting down VM
WARN/dalvikvm(20881): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emx.OnDaMove/com.emx.OnDaMove.SpotMe}: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at com.emx.OnDaMove.SpotMe.onCreate(SpotMe.java:42)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20881):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: I have posted the logcat.. Can You please tell me now??

Answer (score 2):

What is HomePage.NearPlaces???  That should be your array of objects.  How is that defined.   That looks to me like you're making a static reference to what should be a non-static object.   How  you define the array of objects that you pass into the instantiation of the array adapter is what's going to make your spinner dynamic at runtime.

Comment: NearPlaces is static list of Address class.

Comment: Exactly.  That should be the dynamic array that you create and pass in at runtime.   It may help to post the code where you define NearPlaces.

Answer (score 1):

As per the code that you have shared might have issue with the resource you are passing to display option as spinner.

Please share the result after you test.

Comment: Try this code     ArrayAdapter<Address> adapter =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,HomePage.NearPlaces, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)                                Share result